# How can i spawn pr2 on gazebo?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I'm trying to do the pr2_simulator_tutorial and i'm blocked in the first tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/StartingPR2Simulation).

I launched empty world as asked in the tutorials (and the world opened in gazebo) :

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

but when i'm trying to spawn a PR2, it doesn't work and i'm getting the following message (I tried first in another terminal and because it was nos working i also tried in the same where i have writen the first roslaunch)

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
RLException: [pr2.launch] is neither a launch file in package [pr2_gazebo] nor is [pr2_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I saw similar questions with answers and i tried to solve my problem but no solutions has worked until now

- writing `roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch` instead of the previous -> it doesn't change anything and i got the same message
- sourcing : i wrote `source devel/setup.bash` again as i've already did -> it doesn't change anything
- i also tried (following this tuto https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/77265386, this one https://programmerclick.com/article/6041534558/ and others that are saying miore or less the same) to `roscore` one terminal and to retry but once again it didn't work

Seemingly, it could have a link with a .zshrc file in which i should add `setopt nomatch` but i don't find it (even using  `locate`)

Maybe the solution is really easy but i didn't find it. I hope someone could help me.

Thanks for reading

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380320/how-can-i-spawn-pr2-on-gazebo-?/) by [samourai](https://answers.ros.org/users/76120/samourai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got an answer so i will share it :
In fact, we can't use pr2 with ros-noetic (it is not available yet) that's why i could'nt spawn the pr2 robot. I don't know if it will be possible and when but for the moment, we can't.

---

Originally posted by [samourai](https://answers.ros.org/users/76120/samourai/) with karma: 16 on 2021-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SamRodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/89124/samrodriguez/) on 2021-11-08**:
Hi, this piece of information should be more readily available. Where did you find out that pr2 is not available for noetic?